# Flutter: How to group messages with similiar time range and only display time once?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Currently I am building a chat App and my goal is to display the "time/date" over the messages. However, since this gets very messy I only want to show the date once over every hour (similiary to Facebook Messenger)[pic of current chat screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfNcr.jpg). Since I am using Firebase, I store every chat with a collection 'messages' that contain a document for every message in that chat. The document contains String:'messageType', String: 'messageContent', String: 'authorUUID' and timestamp timestamp.

I thought about building a Map that combines timestamp and Content, but since I am a beginner I am not sure if this approach is right. Thank you very much!

As of now my code looks the following:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:native_now/app_constants/app_colors.dart';
import 'package:native_now/models/chat_message_model.dart';

class ChatMessageTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final ChatMessageModel chatMessageModel;

  const ChatMessageTile({Key key, this.chatMessageModel}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 14, right: 14, top: 10, bottom: 10),
      child: Column(
        children: [ chatMessageModel.timestamp.toDate().toLocal().hour != DateTime.now().hour ?
          Text(chatMessageModel.getRelevantTime(),
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .bodyText2
                  .copyWith(color: AppColors.grey,fontSize: 12)) : Container(),
          SizedBox(height: 4,),
          Align(
              alignment: (chatMessageModel.userIsSender()
                  ? Alignment.topRight
                  : Alignment.topLeft),
              child: Stack(alignment: Alignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                      color: (chatMessageModel.userIsSender()
                          ? AppColors.pureBlue
                          : AppColors.onyx),
                    ),
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, right: 12, bottom: 12, top: 12),
                    child: Container(
                      child: Text(
                        chatMessageModel.messageContent,
                        style: Theme.of(context)
                            .textTheme
                            .bodyText1
                            .copyWith(color: AppColors.white),textAlign: (chatMessageModel.userIsSender()
                          ? TextAlign.right
                          : TextAlign.left),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  /*Positioned(
                      right: 2,
                      bottom: 2,
                      child: Text(chatMessageModel.getRelevantTime(),
                          style: Theme.of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .bodyText2
                              .copyWith(color: AppColors.onyx,fontSize: 12))), */
                ],
              )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}



class ChatMessageModel {
  final String messageContent;
  final String messageType;
  final Timestamp timestamp;
  final String authorUUID;
  final DocumentReference documentReference;
  final bool messageRead;
  final bool isLiked;

  ChatMessageModel(this.messageContent, this.messageType,
      this.documentReference, this.timestamp, this.authorUUID, this.messageRead,
      this.isLiked);

  ChatMessageModel.fromDocumentSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot)
      : messageContent = documentSnapshot.get("messageContent"),
        messageType = documentSnapshot.get("messageType"),
        timestamp = documentSnapshot.get("timestamp"),
        authorUUID = documentSnapshot.get("authorUUID"),
        documentReference = documentSnapshot.reference,
        messageRead = false,
        isLiked = false;


 final List<ChatMessageModel> recentMessages;


  List<Map<String, Object>> get groupedTimeBlocks {
    return List.generate(messageContent.length, (index) {
      final hour = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(hours: index));
      for (var i = 0; i < messageContent.length; i++) {
        if (recentMessages[i].timestamp
            .toDate()
            .toLocal()
            .hour == hour.hour) {}
      }
      return {
        'content': messageContent,
        'timestamp': timestamp.toDate().toLocal()};
    });
  }
```

Comment: One way would be to `compare` timestamp(day&&month&&year) of each message with the timestamp of `previous` and `next` message and decide whether to show `date` near this message or not. Note that you need a little bit extra logic for handling boundary cases and to check whether `date` should be above or below the current message. Hope this helps.